# Request ajax to file not control PHP in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, post

I have an own file that receives for post a request ajax, But the request never comes.

**In a view:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#bloquear").click(function(e){
            $.post("proyectodam/app/Lib/ServerSocket.php", {op: 1});
        });
    });
</script>
```

The php I have it in a directory that I have created,His namespaces:

```
namespace proyectodam\Lib;
```

**file PHP:**

```
    <?php 
namespace proyectodam\Lib;

try{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $address = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = 5555;
    // Create a TCP Stream socket
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP); // 0 for  SQL_TCP
    // Bind the socket to an address/port
    socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');  //0 for localhost
    // Start listening for connections
    socket_listen($sock);
    //loop and listen
    while(true){
      /* Accept incoming  requests and handle them as child processes */
      $client = socket_accept($sock);
      //$_SESSION[socket_getpeername($client, AF_INET, 5555)] = socket_getpeername($client, AF_INET, 5555);
      // Read the input  from the client – 1024000 bytes
      //$input = socket_read($client, 1024000);
      // from here you need to do your database stuff
      // and handle the response 

       // Display output  back to client
      if(isset($_POST["op"])){
          $message = 1;
          socket_write($client, $message, strlen($message));
      }
      socket_close($client);
    }
    // Close the master sockets
    socket_close($sock);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

**Client java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClienteSocket{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try {
            Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());

            String op;
            while((op = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(op);
            }

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

That fails?

Comment: Have you made sure `proyectodam/app/Lib/ServerSocket.php` location/file is accessible from the browser ??

Comment: I think that your question does not say too much, but why not just include the file into your route controller?

Comment: My file php is a server socket that this is runing on line of commands, I need that from a send the information to spend him to the verver and this one to the client pd: I manage to connect client with server

Comment: It me has not worked, I have the parti of the client in java

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a post request to `proyectodam/app/Lib/ServerSocket.php`  You need to make sure that you have a file in `/public/proyectodam/app/Lib/ServerSocket.php`

What I would suggest doing however is making an api endpoint such as:

```
Route::post('socket', function() {
    return new ClientSocket();
}
```

And then have your client socket library class be:

```
<?php 
namespace proyectodam\Lib;

class ClienteSocket {

public function __construct() 
{
  try{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $address = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = 5555;

    // Create a TCP Stream socket
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP); // 0 for  SQL_TCP

    // Bind the socket to an address/port
    socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');  //0 for localhost

    // Start listening for connections
    socket_listen($sock);

    //loop and listen
    while(true){
        /* Accept incoming  requests and handle them as child processes */
        $client = socket_accept($sock);

        //$_SESSION[socket_getpeername($client, AF_INET, 5555)] = socket_getpeername($client, AF_INET, 5555);

        // Read the input  from the client – 1024000 bytes
        //$input = socket_read($client, 1024000);
        // from here you need to do your database stuff
        // and handle the response 

        // Display output  back to client
        if(isset($_POST["op"])){
            $message = 1;
            socket_write($client, $message, strlen($message));
        }
        socket_close($client);
    }

    // Close the master sockets
    socket_close($sock);
  } catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}
}
```

Comment: not mistakes, I do not receive dataof the request ajax to the server

Comment: If you are getting no errors, then what is the problem.  It sounds like it may not be a laravel issue, but rather an issue with your actual script you are using.

Comment: Where your to put client socket is server socket, my client is in java

Comment: I need a functional example, am driven to despair by this problem :(